# Using direct sums, construct an inseparable Hilbert space with an uncountable orthonormal basis

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, orthonormal

Using direct sums, construct an inseparable Hilbert space with an uncountable orthonormal basis.

This is Problem 13 in Chapter II in Reed & Simon, and I'm really stuck on this one. Would something like $\{0,1\}^{\mathbb{N}}$ work? I'm not sure this satisfies all the properties, though.

Comment: take the Hilbert sum of uncountably many copies of $\mathbb{C}$

Comment: @Norbert, what would the orthonormal basis be then, though?

Comment: Say you have the direct sum of $|\mathbb C|$ many copies of $\mathbb C$. Then, an ONB is given by $e_z(z) = 1$ and $e_z(x) = 0$ for $z\ne x$.

Comment: @user251257, why would that be a Hilbert space, though? I know that you can take a countable direct sum of Hilbert spaces, but I'm not sure there's any result that says you can do the same uncountably to get another Hilbert space.

Comment: @Ryker scroll down to direct sum of Hilbert space: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_sum_of_modules

Comment: @user251257, thanks, I did, although they don't really make a distinction between countable and uncountable sums, they just say infinite. I wonder whether that's because it holds for both or because the article isn't entirely correct and precise.

Comment: @Ryker infinite sum is just the integral with respect to the counting measure

Answer (score 2):

Let $\mu$ be counting measure on $\mathbb{R}$. Then $L^2_{\mu}(\mathbb{R})$ is uncountable with complete orthonormal basis $\{ e_{r} \}_{r\in\mathbb{R}}$, where $e_{r}(x)=0$ for $x \ne r$ and $e_{r}(r)=1$. Every $x \in L^2_{\mu}(\mathbb{R})$ is a function that is non-zero for at most countably many points of $\mathbb{R}$, with norm $\|x\|=\sqrt{\sum_{t\in\mathbb{R}}|x(t)|^2}$.

Comment: Hmm, it's not a direct sum, though.

Comment: @Ryker it is the same...

Comment: @Ryker : Functions from an index set $\mathbb{R}$ into $\mathbb{C}$ for which the sum of the squares of range values is finite. This is a direct sum of copies of $\mathbb{C}$.